# gnome-terminal multi-tab title position

Tags: gnome-terminal

[image: screenshot]

After upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04, the Gnome Terminal tab title was set to the tab center.

How can I set the title to the left position of the tab?

Comment: Oh, is it so important? :)

Comment: You can change the name of the tab, but I don't think there is an option to align it. Someone else can answer probably.

Comment: There's no config option for this. Probably it's a one-line change in the source, but I don't think it's worth the hassle. I myself really hated it when the change was made (I switched to such a gnome-terminal version about a year ago), but got used to it in just a few days and it didn't bug me anymore.

Comment: I don't like the title in the center position, this will bother me.

Comment: This design change affects other GNOME applications as well -- notably ["Web"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_(web_browser)), and gedit.  It's like the team suddenly decided that the way we've always done tabs is wrong and they are going to fix that for us.  The problem is, centered tabs don't look like tabs.  I think people don't really need to read the contents of the tabs, so much as they need the tabs themselves to be placed in a consistent location that doesn't change if a new tab is added.  GNOME, give us the choice.  Mostly, I've solve this for myself by using the MATE replacements.

Comment: @nobar But mate-terminal does not support the new scrollbar style. I plan to maintained a gnome-terminal fork and rollback the tab label.

Comment: Yesterday I was using `gedit` when I accidentally hit some key sequence that opened a new tab.  Because of the new layout, I didn't notice the new tab and all I could see was that my text had disappeared.  I spent a few minutes frantically trying to recover the text from other locations before I came back and discovered what had actually happened.  Tabs should look like tabs.  It matters.

Comment: Compounding the location problem, the current "Ambiant-MATE" theme *barely* differentiates the appearance of the currently active tab in (especially in `gedit`) -- this makes no sense at all.  This, at least, can be partially customized with "Appearance Preferences"->"Customize Theme"->"Controls".  However, this doesn't allow the tab appearance to be controlled independently from other significant theme elements.  *The best solution that I have found to these problems is to use `pluma` rather than `gedit` for most purposes.*

Comment: I guess I shouldn't be too critical that GNOME's `gedit` doesn't render perfectly under MATE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me answer my question.

1. Download the gnome-terminal source package

   ```
   apt-get source gnome-terminal
   ```
2. Install the build dependencies required for gnome-terminal

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep gnome-terminal
   ```
3. Rollback the change below

> https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal/commit/468a18f5e21b42ee0efedf3d86203fbc4e02807e

4. Repackage the source code

   ```
   tar zcf gnome-terminal_3.14.2.orig.tar.gz gnome-terminal-3.14.2
   ```
5. Build new gnome-terminal package

   ```
   debuild -b
   ```
6. Install the new gnome-terminal package

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i gnome-terminal_xxx.deb
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to replace Gnome terminal with MATE terminal.

```
apt-get install mate-terminal
```

Comment: Thank you for you recommend, but the font in mate-terminal seems weird.

See following screenshot:

gnome-terminal: http://imgur.com/cv8s8uR
mate-terminal: http://imgur.com/jq6RmgX